# How to implement react-native-dark-mode in ios

Tags: ios, react-native

Hi all i want to try implement react-native-dark-mode but not worked in my project.
    "react-native": "0.61.5"

I Already try like this :

```
import { useDarkMode } from 'react-native-dark-mode'

export default class Login extends Component {
    render(){
    const isDarkMode = useDarkMode() // i think this make error
       return(
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? 'black' : 'white' }}></View>
       )
    }
}
```

This my error
[error-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djp41.png)

any solutions?

Comment: hooks can only be able to use inside the functional component. Instead of class you need to make functional component

Comment: useDarkMode is a hook you can use it only in functional component. For class component use DarkModeProvider

Comment: I have posted a full answer on your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your scenario [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) can only be used inside the [functional components](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/react-native/functional-vs-class-components/)

**Example of functional component usage:**

```
import { useDarkMode } from 'react-native-dark-mode'

function Component() {
    const isDarkMode = useDarkMode()
    return <View style={{ backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? 'black' : 'white' }} />
}
```

**Example of class component usage:**

**You can play around with DarkModeContext. Just make sure to wrap your application in a DarkModeProvider with no props to avoid getting a value of current.**

1 - Setup context provider for the app.

```
// App.js or top of the hierarchy in your app
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {DarkModeProvider} from 'react-native-dark-mode';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DarkModeProvider>
        <YourApp />
      </DarkModeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

2 - Use the context with **contextType** or context consumer.

```
// class based component with contextType
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import {DarkModeContext} from 'react-native-dark-mode';

export default class HelloWorldText extends Component {
  static contextType = DarkModeContext;
  render() {
    const isDarkMode = this.context === 'dark';
    return (
      <Text style={{color: isDarkMode ? '#ffffff' : '#000000'}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Text>
    );
  }
}
```

3 - Final class based component

```
// class based component with context consumer
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import {DarkModeContext} from 'react-native-dark-mode';

export default class HelloWorldText extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DarkModeContext.Consumer>
        {mode => (
          <Text style={{color: mode === 'dark' ? '#ffffff' : '#000000'}}>
            {this.props.children}
          </Text>
        )}
      </DarkModeContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to know about the context, you can find more detail in [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) page. It is really useful feature for both, class and function components.

Comment: but is that can to put in outside class? i want to put in my stylesheet